# Relative path in JLabel HTML

Tags: java, html, relative-path, jlabel

I am trying to make JLabel show an html which is referencing an image using a relative path.
But I cannot make JLabel locate the image. It works fine when I am using absolute path.

I have tried running the program from the command line or from eclipse and add dialog to show me where is the current working directory but for avail.
I have therefor came to the conclusion that the image is not searched in the current directory - which brings me to the point. where is the image looked for?

here is a test code that show what I am doing:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HTMLLabel extends JFrame {
    public HTMLLabel() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, 
                System.getProperty("user.dir"));

         String html = "<html>\n" +
        "   <body>\n" +
        "       <div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n" + 
        "           <img src=\"file://s.png\">\n"+
        "       </div>\n"+
        "   </body>\n"+
        "</html>";

         JLabel label = new JLabel(html);
         add(label);

         pack();
         setVisible(true);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new HTMLLabel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that on windows the path can indeed be set to relative using something like that:

<img src=\"file:subdir/s.png\">

But on ubuntu that does not work. On Ubuntu it only works w/o the subdir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function to prepare the html text for the JLabel to display images relative to the package of a class.

```
public static String prepareHtmlToJLabelText(Class relativeClass, String html) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=['\"](.*?)['\"]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    while (m.find()) {
        html = html.replace(m.group(), "src='" + relativeClass.getResource(m.group(1)) + "'");
    }
    return html;
}
```

The function replace the content of the "src" attribute to make it relative to the provider class.

Example:

```
jLabel.setText(prepareHtmlToJLabelText(this.getClass(), "<html><div style='text-align: center;'><img src='imageA.png'></div>Bla bla bla...<div style='text-align: center;'><img src='imageB.png'></div>"));
```

Anyway for a real html support use JEditorPane.

Answer (score 3):

I see two variants:

I don't know why but for me this works

```
"                       <img src=\"file:s.png\">\n"+
```

assuming that s.png is in current working directory.

Another variant that seems more appropriate for me is:

```
URL url = HTMLLabel.class.getResource( "/s.png" );
  String html = "<html>\n" +
    "       <body>\n" +
    "               <div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n" + 
    "                       <img src=\""+url+"\">\n"+
    "               </div>\n"+
    "       </body>\n"+
    "</html>";
```

Comment: Interesting I guess java automatically corrects the incomplete scheme + path to file:/// but fails on file://s.png

Comment: It's really strange because java also corrects doubling of path separators (e.g. /gif//s.png and /gif///s.png to /gif/s.png )

Comment: contexte, indeed it works with
  <img src=\"file:s.png\">\n" +
which is very strange but unfortunately I need it in a specific folder under the working directory and
  <img src=\"file:subdir/s.png\">\n" +
Does not work.

About the second solution you and jitter suggest, it is a bit of a problem, because the html is not hardcoded in the program that actually put it in the JLabel - it is created by another program and placed in a subdir of the working directory. It would require me to parse the html and replace the image src attribute with a absolute path - something I with to avoid.

Comment: Do you think it could be a platform thingy? I am running ubuntu.

Comment: Look, I'm also working on Ubuntu. 8.10 to be precise. This works for me: <img src=\"file:subdir/s.png\"> . Where subdir is under current wirking directory.

Comment: contexte, are you using openJDK or sun's java, maybe the difference comes from there.

Comment: This is my test - http://rapidshare.com/files/296357866/test_label.zip.html . Download, extract and run "java HTMLLabel". For me it works. I don't know how else I can help you:(

Comment: contexte, Thank you so very very much. it works now. you were right all along. I don't know what stupid mistake I have done. but now it works as you suggested from the start.
I don't believe I wasted days on this....
Thanks again for your persistence and dedication to help me.

BTW the project you helped me with is an open source project which is hosted on source forge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/periman/

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even doing it like this? Just use this `JLabel(Icon image)` constructor

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(createImageIcon("s.png","description"));

protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
  java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
  if (imgURL != null) {
    return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
  } else {
    System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
    return null;
  }
}
```

---

Or if you insist on the html variant.

btw The file protocol uses 3 slashes (`file://s.png` is invalid) and `file:///s.png` would mean `C:\s.png`. If the image resides in the starting directory you could use.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String html =
  "<html>\n" +
     "<body>\n" +
        "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n" +
          "<img src=\"file:///"+path+"/s.png\">\n"+
        "</div>\n"+
     "</body>\n"+
  "</html>";
```

But I make no guarantees about the 2nd solution.

Comment: jitter, The reason I don't directly set the icon for the label is because there are two different programs involved here one that choose the html and one for showing it.
and that is why I cannot use any of your solution (easily). but thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

i just replaced your

```
<img src=\"file://s.png\">\n"
//with
<img src=\"file:///s.png\">\n"+
```

and that solved the problem

NOTE: i placed the s.png file in the src/java folder